# Kendo Grid with MVVM, AJAX - operations with grids

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Looking for a solution on this using KendoUI MVVM:
There are two grids – data in first grid is returned from a controller’s action say GetData(). This grid has a column with checkbox.
User can select the rows in first grid by checking on the checkbox. On clicking a button – all the rows selected from first grid should get added to second grid. The second grid has 3 more columns extra and the other columns are quite similar to the one’s in first grid.
Could somebody post solution on this please. It’s quite urgent.

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public bool? ChooseItem { get; set; }
        public int Quantity{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Grid1**

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>
        ()
        .Name("grid1")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerID).Filterable(false).Title("<b>CustID</b>").Width(170);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerName).Title("<b>Description</b>").Width(250);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ChooseItem)
        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='rowSelected' />");
        })
        .Selectable()
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable(x => x.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-bind", "source: gridSource1" } })
            .EnableCustomBinding(true)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(15)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"))
            )
            )

<button id="btnAddMulti" type="button">Add LineItem </button>
```

**Grid2**

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>
        ()
        .Name("grid2")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerID).Filterable(false).Title("<b>CustID</b>").Width(170);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerName).Title("<b>Description</b>").Width(250);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity)
        .ClientTemplate("<input type='text' id='itemQty' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerID)
        .ClientTemplate("<input type='button' id='btnAdd' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerID)
        .ClientTemplate("<input type='button' id='btnDelete' />");
        })
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-bind", "source: gridSource2" } })
            .EnableCustomBinding(true)          
            )
            )

var viewModel = kendo.observable({

        gridSource1: [],
    gridSource2: [],
})
$('#btnAddMulti').click(function () {
        var sourcegrid = $('#grid1').data('kendoGrid'); 
        var destinationgrid = $('#grid2').data('kendoGrid'); 

//ToDo: copy all the rows in destinationgrid which are marked checked in sourcegrid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , this is just an example

**My view**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleModel>()
    .Name("grid12")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentclass).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox_#=inx#' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleDescription);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleCode);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleItems);
    })
     // .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        // .AutoBind(true)
        .Pageable()
            .Navigatable()
        //.Filterable()
             .Sortable()
             .Groupable()
        //.Events(events => events.DataBound("_GridItemDataBound"))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.inx))
           //.PageSize(1)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Test"))
     )
  )


 <div id="divasd">
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#grid12').on("click", ".chkbxq", function (e) {
                    var selectedTd = $(this).is(':checked');

                    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
                    var cellIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index();
                    var grid = $("#grid12").data("kendoGrid");
                    var datatItem = grid.dataItem(grid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + cellIndex + ')'));

                    if (selectedTd == true) {
                        sampleItem = datatItem.SampleItems;
                        sampleCode = datatItem.SampleCode;
                        sampledescription = datatItem.SampleDescription;

                        datavalueitem = sampleItem + "--" + sampleCode + "--" + sampledescription;

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("NewGridView", "Test")',
                            type: "Post",
                            data: { sampleItem: sampleItem, sampleCode: sampleCode, sampledescription: sampledescription },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (result) {

                                $("#mygrid").val(null);
                                var customDataList = $('#grid');
                                customDataList.empty();
                                customDataList.append(result.Data);
                                customDataList.append(result.Data);
                                $("#divasd").html('');
                                $("#divasd").append(result.Data);



                                $('#grid12').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                                $('#grid12').data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                                                                $("#divasd").kendoGrid({
                                                                    dataSource: result,
                                                                    sortable: true,
                                                                    pageable: {
                                                                        refresh: true,
                                                                        pageSizes: true
                                                                    },
                                                                    columns: [{
                                                                        field: "SampleDescription",
                                                                        width: 90,
                                                                    }, {
                                                                        field: "SampleCode",
                                                                        width: 90,
                                                                    }, {
                                                                        width: 100,
                                                                        field: "SampleItems"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                                });


                            }
                        });
                    }


                });

   });
</script>
```

**Model**

```
 public class SampleModel
    {
        public int inx { get; set; }
        public bool studentclass { get; set; }
        public string SampleDescription { get; set; }
        public string SampleCode { get; set; }
        public string SampleItems { get; set; }
}
```

New Grid is bind on checkBox Check not in Buttonclick.

Comment: Well, the add to another grid has to happen on a button (outside grid) and not on every checkbox click. On the button click, it has to capture all the checked rows and then add the same to another grid. Plus, the header of checkbox column is also a checkbox, so if that is checked/unchecked, all the checkboxes in that column are checked/unchecked.

Comment: I just give you demo on checkbox check you can do it on button. If you have any problem with button click then let me know.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what does NewGridView() return ?

And how is mygrid defined ? What is 'grid' ?

$("#mygrid").val(null);
                                var customDataList = $('#grid');
                                customDataList.empty();
                                customDataList.append(result.Data);
                                customDataList.append(result.Data);

Comment: I tried the above example. It doesn't populate any data in the destination grid !